# How to go to another page without keeping scroll position with React

Tags: reactjs, scroll, routes, next.js, single-page-application

I'm working on a project with Next/React. When I click on a button which is supposed to bring me to another page, the scroll position is kept, meaning that I arrive X pixels down on the new page.

I added the following code to the page:

```
if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

It works. But the thing is, before it works, the page is displayed X pixels down around 1 sec or less before it goes to the top.

Comment: DId you find out what is the root cause of "The scroll position is kept"?
I found similar issue today and couldnt find any root cause related with scroll position.
Is it an automatic feature from react router?

Answer (score 1):

Add the scrolling to the top code in the `useEffect` hook or `componentDidMount` of your page component. You'll need to add this to every page components. I'd recommend moving it into a custom hook and calling it.

For your `useEffect` do this:

```
useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), []);
```

This will ensure once the component is mounted, it will scroll to the top. The empty `[]` dependency array ensures it only gets executed once when the component is mounted.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that's what I did and it goes to the previous page position first then goes to the top.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can try:

> First

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollLeft = 0;` you can add this code inside componentDidUpdate if it a class component or inside useEffect if it is a function component

> Second

```
history.listen((location, action) => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), []);
```

This code shows the scroll effect but i want to direct open to top without scrolling. You can visit https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools, in this page when I click side nav-link in this case open top to page without scrolling.